# How to run a system command on a file in the HDFS?

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I have a set of files in my HDFS. I need to run a system command on all these files from  java using the API. How do I do it without getting the files into the local filesystem? Is it even possible?

I am very new to Hadoop; Please explain the solutions in simple terms.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you find a solution for your question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is very much possible. Have a look at this link which shows you how to use the [HDFS API](https://www.inkling.com/read/hadoop-definitive-guide-tom-white-3rd/chapter-3/the-java-interface)